# How to remove bathroom sink drain with no lock nut

Tags: bathroom, drain, sink

I'm trying to get this pipe out but I have no idea how to remove it from the sink.  Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How about a picture from the top. Sometimes the drain cover unscrews like in a bathtub.

Comment: Try unscrewing using a pair of heavy needle nose pliers from the top if there is a cross brace , I have seen this on older sinks and many tubs. A tub wrench usually won’t fit in a sink this is why I suggest heavy needle nose pliers.

Comment: I can't get the picture size small enough to load but I'll try the pliers.  THANK YOU!

Comment: No dice.  Can't get it to unscrew and can't get a pic with a small enough file size

Comment: You put the pliers in then use a screwdriver as a lever on the handles to provide more force - just trying to twist on the handles of the pliers, well if you are Braun Strowmann you may succeed...

Comment: Can't tell but it looks like it's threaded in.  Try a 2-prong attack: treat the joint liberally with some rust-remover or similar fluid designed to free up frozen joints; wait a day maybe,  and use a long-handled strap wrench to try to rotate the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Pliers and screwdriver are a poor substitute for the proper tool. ( *They may or may not work but are not easy to use and may result in bending or damaging the thin metal of the drain basket without getting it to turn* )

The proper tool is a [Drain Removal Wrench](https://www.lowes.com/pd/BrassCraft-Drain-Removal-Wrench/999903545)

It has two ends, one small one large, with nubs that fit into the slots of the drain. It has flat sides so you can get a large adjustable wrench ( *crescent wrench* ) on it  or It has holes in the handle so you can put a screwdriver through them to act as a lever for turning leverage.

You need a way to keep the pipe and basket underneath form turning and since you do not have a tradition basket with nut you will need a strap wrench or adjustable pliers ( *channel locks* ) to hold the pipe assembly. It will probably take 2 people, On to hold the assemble under the sink while the other try to turn the drain wrench counterclockwise.

Based on the photo it has some corrosion and If this does not work you may have to cut it off from below with reciprocating saw ( *saws-all* )

Comment: Cutting it off from below would probably leave the critical assembly still attached, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a rotary tool with a cutoff disc and slice the pipe from above right below the upper flange. By cutting the flange off you should release everything to drop out below. Brace your hands well against the sink to keep the tool stable.

Comment: I love having an exmechanic for a dad.  I have access to all of these things!  Thank you!  Wanna replace the damn thing without calling the landlord cause my 150 gal aquarium is cracked from drilling.  Need to fix that before she's sees the Beast for the first time!

Comment: You're welcome. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works.